# Uploading photos to e-Mail from Swift

Tags: ios, swift, photo

I am writing an app that has a simple form with a photo upload tool, the user uploads their photo to the form and it is displayed in an image view, i then want that image to be in the blank e-Mail that opens up upon clicking submit. I am using the following code to try and achieve this:

`let messageBody = "\n\nPhoto: \(imageView.image!)"`

The photo gets uploaded and shows in the image view fine but the email displays the following where the image is supposed to be " size {1334, 70} orientation 0 scale 1.000000"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your code (or my previous answer) won't work because you are converting the image to a string (messageBody). And it basically shows you a string of information about the image. So your only option is to write the message in HTML (and set isHTML to **true**). The good news is that it isn't too hard.

I think the code below should work.

```
let messageBody = "<html><body>Photo:<img src=\"yourImage.png\"></body></html>"
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how i can tell it to reference the imageView for the image source rather than a file embedded in the project?

Comment: Your question is rather confusing. Where do you upload the photo from? The camera roll or a link? Why would the image be imbedded in the project? You don't know how the user looks. If you want the user to choose a photo from his/her camera roll, then use UIIMagePicker to get the image and then set it as the imageView's image. Is that what you want?